# Is there extra risk in owning an ADR vs. the underlying stock?

Tags: risk, risk-management, adr, stocks

One of my favorite on-again-off-again recovery plays is Mittal Steel (NYSE: MT).

I buy the MT ADR there (American Depositary Receipt) because I live in the US.

Am I exposing myself to any extra risk owning the ADR instead of the underlying stock? Has there ever been any sticky issues with ADRs not performing exactly like the underlying stock?

I understand the benefits of ADRs, just wondering if there are downsides.

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/will-adr-owner-enjoy-same-benefit-as-common-shares-holders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the ADR will trade on a separate exchange from the underlying one, and can (and does) see fluctuations in price that do not match the (exchange corrected) fluctuations that occur in the original market.

You are probably exposing yourself to additional risk that is related to:

- Financial market volatility
- Trading patterns in the american market
- Taxation, trade and other issues that stem from international relations (imagine an ADR where the foreign country's relations with the US quickly deteriorate; it's USD value may fall in lock-step, dropping to below its native currency value)
- Loss of liquidity (ADRs often tend to be more difficult to sell)

Comment: Wouldn't those fluctuations actually present an arbitrage opportunity?  At some point the price of the ADR has to come in line with the price of the security in the home market.

Comment: The added complexities both increases the opportunity for arbitrage (giving incentive to speculators) and makes value calculations more difficult (making it more likely that essentially correct out of synch pricing is mistaken for an arbitrage opportunity). Yes, there will be points where the ADR will price in correlation to the underlying security, but they are not reliably predictable points.

Comment: @EricPetroelje You are correct about the potential for ADR arbitrage. I used to do that for a past employer. But the amounts to be earned through ADR arb trades were usually small, and a combination of synchronization issues, taxes and other costs, resulted in lean pickings. But it was a nice straightforward strategy, and easy to monitor for occasional mispricings and profit opportunities.

Comment: @EllieKesselman, So the question is should you buy the ADR or the non-ADR? Which is better to put money into? Or do you buy 50/50?

Comment: What happens if the issuing bank goes bankrupt? see question here? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/137307/do-you-lose-adrs-investment-if-the-issuing-bank-goes-bankrupt

Comment: @Pacerier It depends how you arb the ADR and its underlying stock. Let's say you want to be long in one and short in the other. If your access to the domestic stock (i.e. trades natively on its home exchange) is good, then short it there and go long the ADR in the US. It would be more difficult to short an ADR (in terms of availability and cost) than the stock. There are other ways to arbitrage using options on the native stock in its domestic markets versus the ADR in the US. It also depends on relative liquidity of the ADR vs the underlying domestic stock. Maybe f/x volatility too.