# Do you lose ADRs Investment if the issuing Bank goes bankrupt?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, adr

If I buy a Foreign Country Stock through an ADR eg,  Citibank and JPMorgan.
And then The US banks almost go broke/bankrupt during the 2008 meltdown (as example), would I lose my ADR and investment, or would I still hold the underlying stock ?